# How can Chomsky hierarchy be applied to languages with alternated letters?

Tags: formal-grammars, chomsky-hierarchy

I have the following grammar, which I know it is regular because it can be represented by a finite state automata:

\begin{array}{l}
\mathrm{S} \rightarrow \mathrm{X} \mid \mathrm{Y} \\
\mathrm{X} \rightarrow \mathrm{a} \mathrm{Y} \mathrm{b} \mid \mathrm{ab} \\
\mathrm{Y} \rightarrow \mathrm{b} \mathrm{X} \mathrm{a} \mid \mathrm{ba}
\end{array}

According to Chomsky hierarchy:

> Type-3 grammars generate the regular languages. Such a grammar
> restricts its rules to a single nonterminal on the left-hand side and
> a right-hand side consisting of a single terminal, possibly followed
> by a single nonterminal (right regular). Alternatively, the right-hand
> side of the grammar can consist of a single terminal, possibly
> preceded by a single nonterminal (left regular).

However, I do not find the hierarchy applied to the grammar. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every regular grammar produces a regular language.

But:

Not every grammar for a regular language is regular.

In other words, a regular language can be described by any of an infinitude of grammars, some of which are regular and some not.

In this case, you can easily create either a left- or a right-regular grammar for your language. For example:

\begin{array}{l}
\mathrm{S} \rightarrow \mathrm{X} \mid \mathrm{Y} \\
\mathrm{X} \rightarrow  \mathrm{X}  \mathrm{a}\mathrm{b} \mid \mathrm{ab} \\
\mathrm{Y} \rightarrow \mathrm{Y}   \mathrm{b}  \mathrm{a} \mid \mathrm{ba}
\end{array}

Of course, that transformation only preserves the language parsed, not the induced parse trees.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)